# glob() variable value substitution in path php?

Tags: php, file, web, directory, glob

I am trying to use glob() in php to return all files that txt files that contain the word "review" in it. These files are located in a director books/(name), so a review of a harry potter book is located in books/harrypotter/ .

```
$bookPath = "books/harrypotter";          //could be any book title
$reviews = glob($bookPath . '/review*.txt');
print_r($reviews);
```

But this just prints a blank array.

```
Array
(
)
```

It works if I replace my variable $bookPath with the actual text like so:

```
$reviews = glob('books/harrypotter/review*.txt');
print_r($reviews);
//prints this

Array
    (
        [0] => books/harrypotter/review1.txt
        [1] => books/harrypotter/review2.txt
        [2] => books/harrypotter/review3.txt
    )
```

My question is, why does it work with the text, but not with the variable replacing the text? I printed out `$bookPath . 'review*txt'` and it looks exactly the same as `"books/harrypotter/review*txt"`

Comment: Strange, I tested with many cases, including yours and it worked. Try with double commas inside glob: glob("$bookPath/review*.txt"); 

Are you really doing it right you showing here? Because your print below your question is missing a dot.

Comment: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your `php` script, run the 1st example, what does it return?

Comment: and if you put everything in the variable? `$bookPath = "books/harrypotter/review*.txt"; $reviews = glob($bookPath);` or add your root folder in front of your path. Are you on a windows server `('\' !== '/')`